# Overriding or Extending Core Interfaces

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, interface

I am trying to add a new getter and setter to `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryTreeInterface`.

I have created a new interface -
 `\Wildcard\CategoriesApi\Api\Data\CategoryTreeInterface`and a new model - `\Wildcard\CategoriesApi\Model\Category`.

When I call the `/V1/categories` endpoint the property is not shown.

However, if I directly add the getter and setter to the core interface, it works.

My `di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryTreeInterface" type="Wildcard\CategoriesApi\Api\Data\CategoryTreeInterface"/>
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category" type="Wildcard\CategoriesApi\Model\Category"/>
    <preference for="Wildcard\CategoriesApi\Api\Data\CategoryTreeInterface" type="Wildcard\CategoriesApi\Model\Category"/>

</config>
```

PHPStorm does highligh the `Wildcard\CategoriesApi\Api\Data\CategoryTreeInterface` in the `type` parameter in the first preference as not being able to resolve. I have triple checked my namespacing and file/folder names but they are all correct.

Can someone please help with how to add my methods to the interface?

Using **Magento 2.1.7**

Comment: Nobody has an idea about this?

Comment: Answer for you question is here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213753/magento-2-override-core-interface-and-model

Comment: @Wildcard27 I need to override same core interface and model file. Have you got any solution ? 
Please let me know.

Comment: Overriding core interface and model classes is simply not possible in Magento 2. You must use the Extension Attributes functionality as explained in the other answer. If you absolutely must override the core classes you could use a Composer patch to change those files, but that is very error-prone and sensitive to issues when upgrading Magento version.