# Magento 2 : Override core Interface and Model

Tags: magento2, overrides, interface

I am trying to override core interface of Customer Group.

I add my custom get and set methods to core Api interface.

> Vendor\magento\customer-module\Api\Data\GroupInterface.php

Where its working fine.

But when i am trying to override it its doesn't seems to be work.

Here i am sharing my module code.

> ZeroCool\AdvacedReviews\Api\Data\GroupInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace ZeroCool\AdvancedReviews\Api\Data\GroupInterface;


interface GroupInterface extends ExtensibleDataInterface
{   
const SHIPPING_METHOD = 'shipping_method';

/**
 * Get shipping method
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getShippingMethod();

/**
 * Set shipping method
 *
 * @param int $shippingMethod
 * @return $this
 */
public function setShippingMethod($shippingMethod);

}
```

> ZeroCool\AdvancedReviews\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Group\Edit\Form">
    <plugin name="add_form_field" type="ZeroCool\AdvancedReviews\Model\Plugin\Form" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Group\Save">
    <plugin name="save_field" type="ZeroCool\AdvancedReviews\Model\Plugin\Form" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Group" type="ZeroCool\AdvancedReviews\Model\Data\Group" /> 
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface" type="ZeroCool\AdvancedReviews\Api\Data\GroupInterface" />
```

There's also one question available but it doesn't have any answers till now.

[Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183940/overriding-or-extending-core-interfaces)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need to change core api model file  ...How to override core api interface .....How to do this ....If u know please help me

Comment: @ManoM 

Could you please help me on this question.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293336/magento-2-override-for-product-custom-option-value-interface-and-model-file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Below solution worked for me.

As per MIKE suggested we can't directly override magento's core interfaces.

So than there's comes role of **Extension Attributes**.

> etc/extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
 <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
    <attribute code="custom_shipping_charge" type="string"/>
</extension_attributes>

<extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface">
    <attribute code="custom_shipping_amount" type="string"/>
</extension_attributes>

</config>
```

> Execute : `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

After that your get and set method will generated under below path.

> magento_root/generated/code/Magento/Customer/Api/Data/GroupExtensionInterface.php

Now you can use those methods.

```
$groups->getCustomShippingAmount();
$groups->setCustomShippingAmount();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How can I override Interface and Mode. Please let me know ? Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionValuesInterface.php

Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value.php

Comment: Could you please help me on this question. 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293336/magento-2-override-for-product-custom-option-value-interface-and-model-file

Comment: as you said get and set methods will be generated in generated folder. they automatically be generated in that folder or we have to generate them?

Comment: Read carefully... :)
I added that after executing bin/magento setup:di:compile you'll get those methods.

Comment: @anonymous in which file i can use getCustomShippingAmount and setCustomShippingAmount methods?

Answer (score 10):

Magento 2 Preference does not allow us to override the interfaces. Preferences are used to specify the implementation classes for the interfaces and overriding implementation classes. **It does not allow to override interface with an interface**

Then, how can we override the interfaces to send our extra informations over the interface? That's where the beautiful concept comes in - **Extensions Attributes**.

From the official doc:

> Extension attributes are new in Magento 2. They are used to extend
>   functionality and often use more complex data types than custom
>   attributes. These attributes do not appear on the GUI.

In your case, if you check the `\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface` interface, you can find these 2 methods at the bottom, which helps you to send your shipping information through this methods.

```
 /**
 * Retrieve existing extension attributes object or create a new one.
 *
 * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupExtensionInterface|null
 */
public function getExtensionAttributes();

/**
 * Set an extension attributes object.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes
 * @return $this
 */
public function setExtensionAttributes(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupExtensionInterface $extensionAttributes);
```

For more information on how to add extension attributes,
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

Comment: How can I override Interface and Mode. Please let me know ? Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionValuesInterface.php Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value.php

Comment: What about the interfaces that does not have these two functions. but I still need to push some data on those objects in API call?

Comment: @Nahid did you get any solution for that, I am also in same situation where my core interface doesn't have extension attribute functions

Answer (score 0):

Please find below answer to add custom description as an extension attribute.

/etc/extension_attributes.xml should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodInterface">
        <attribute code="method_description" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

In the etc/di.xml file add a plugin for overriding modelToDataObject() in Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodConverter">
        <plugin name="add_description_to_carrier" type="<Vendor>\<module>\Plugin\Carrier\Description" disabled="false" sortOrder="30"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

The plugin file Vendor\module\Plugin\Carrier\Description.php should be like this:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\module\Plugin\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodExtensionFactory;

/**
 * Class Description
 * 
 */
class Description
{
    /**
     * @var ShippingMethodExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $extensionFactory;

    /**
     * Description constructor.
     * @param ShippingMethodExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ShippingMethodExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param $subject
     * @param $result
     * @param $rateModel
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterModelToDataObject($subject, $result, $rateModel)
    {
        $extensionAttribute = $result->getExtensionAttributes() ?
            $result->getExtensionAttributes()
            :
            $this->extensionFactory->create()
        ;
        $extensionAttribute->setMethodDescription($rateModel->getMethodDescription());
        $result->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttribute);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

After all this you will get that description on fronend as below:

```
<div data-bind="text: method.extension_attributes.method_description"></div>
```

Comment: Could you please help me on this question. 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293336/magento-2-override-for-product-custom-option-value-interface-and-model-file