# Unable to override interface in magento2

Tags: overrides, magento-2.2.5, interface

I want to declare new method in interface "Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface"

I tried to override interface using di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface" type="Custom\DownloadableImport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface" />
<preference for="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregator" type="Custom\DownloadableImport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregator" />
```

But this doesn't seems  to work. Is there any way to override interface in magento2

Answer (score 0):

we can't directly override Magento's core interfaces.

So then their use of **Extension Attributes.**

> etc/extension_attributes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">

 <extension_attributes for="Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import\ErrorProcessing\ProcessingErrorAggregatorInterface">
    <attribute code="custom_processing_error" type="string"/>
</extension_attributes>

</config>
```

**useful link**

[Magento 2 : Override core Interface and Model](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213753/magento-2-override-core-interface-and-model)

I hope this will help you...!